# laravel 5 NotFoundHttpException occurrence

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I have noticed that I get this error a lot.  Say I start creating a CRUD for a projects table, but in the Controller I only do index, create and show.  I get everything working with these functions as they should be.

At a later point, say I decide to add an edit function, something simple like

```
public function edit(Project $project)
{
    return view('projects.edit', compact('project'));
}
```

If I then try to edit the project, I get

```
NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 143:
```

Even if I simply return a String I get the same Exception.  From experience, if I restarted my entire project and added the edit function from the start, then it would work without problem.

I have tried clearing caches, deleting files in the storage folder, everything I can think off.  Nothing seems to work however.  This project is now quite large, and I really do not want to start it again.

I have checked route:list and the route is there and its all pointing to the correct locations.  If I select edit, the page that shows the error has a url like

```
http://localhost:8000/projects//edit
```

So it is missing the id between projects/ and /edit.  If I manually enter the id, then the page displays fine.

Is there anything I can do to get rid of this error without having to restart my project?

Thanks

**Update**
My routes are done like so

```
Route::model('projects', 'Project');
Route::bind('projects', function($value, $route) {
    return App\Project::whereId($value)->first();
});
Route::resource('projects', 'ProjectsController');
```

This is my link to edit

```
{!! link_to_route('projects.edit', 'Edit', array($project->slug), array('class' => 'btn btn-info')) !!}
```

And the Controller is

```
public function edit(Project $project)
{
     $clients = Client::lists('clientName', 'id');
     $users = User::lists('userName', 'id');
     return View::make('projects.edit', compact('project', 'clients', 'users'));
}
```

My show works fine, and I am passing that a Project variable.  As I say, it I redone my project with the edit in from the start, I know it will work (as I have done it before).

Thanks

Comment: try this `Route::get('/delete','ResourceController@delete');` create delete method in your controller but if you do this  `Route::get('/photo/delete','ResourceController@delete');`  it will be handled by the show method.

Answer (score 3):

When you create `edit` URL you need to pass `id` to create valid URL, in this case it should be for example `projects/1/edit` when you want to edit project with `id=1`. Otherwise you will get this `NotFoundHttpException` because in your routes there is no route  `projects//edit` but there is probably route `projects/{id}/edit`

Comment: I understand what you mean, but the routes are automatically made using resource.  I pass it a projects object which is how I do it for all other Objects and they all work fine.  This error seems to occur if I delay the creation of a function.  For instance, I have just added a delete function to the controller, and I get  MethodNotAllowedHttpException even though its the same code as I use successfully in other places.

Comment: @kate_hudson You should include in your question the view where you create link for edit and the controller method where you pass data for this view

Comment: I have updated the OP to include them details.  Thanks